# Fetching nested objet and MultipleBagFetchException

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I use spring boot 3

```
@Entity
public class Editor{

    @Id
    public Long editorId;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "editor", orphanRemoval = true, cascade = {CascadeType.ALL})
    List<Person> persons;

}

@Entity
public class Person{

    @Id
    public Long personId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "PERSON_PERSONACTIVITE", schema = "", joinColumns = {@JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "PERSON_ACTIVIES_ID", nullable = false, updatable = false) })
    private List<PersonActivies> personActivites

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "EDITOR_ID", nullable = false)
    @NotNull
    private Editor editor;

}

@Entity
public class PersonActivies{
    @Id
    public Long personActivitesId;

    @ManyToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy = "personActivites")
    private List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();

}
```

I try to get everything in one query.

```
select e from Editor e Join fetch e.persons p Join fetch p.personActivites
```

I get this error

```
cannot simultaneously fetch multiple bags
```

I have read theses link about this issue

https://www.baeldung.com/java-hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception
https://vladmihalcea.com/hibernate-multiplebagfetchexception/

They don't talk about fetching nested object.

I tried to convert in Perso the list to Set, but I get

failed to lazily initialize a collection of role

Answer (score 0):

They don't talk about that because they don't have a good answer for that in general. In you particular case, it could be as simple as replacing `List` with `Set` in the entity model, but I think this is a perfect use case for [Blaze-Persistence Entity Views](https://github.com/Blazebit/blaze-persistence#entity-view-usage).

I created the library to allow easy mapping between JPA models and custom interface or abstract class defined models, something like Spring Data Projections on steroids. The idea is that you define your target structure(domain model) the way you like and map attributes(getters) via JPQL expressions to the entity model.

A DTO model for your use case could look like the following with Blaze-Persistence Entity-Views:

```
@EntityView(Editor.class)
public interface EditorDto {
    @IdMapping
    Long getEditorId();
    Set<PersonDto> getPersons();

    @EntityView(Person.class)
    interface PersonDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getPersonId();
        Set<PersonActiviesDto> getPersonActivites();
    }

    @EntityView(PersonActivies.class)
    interface PersonActiviesDto {
        @IdMapping
        Long getPersonActivitesId();
        String getName();
    }
}
```

Querying is a matter of applying the entity view to a query, the simplest being just a query by id.

`EditorDto a = entityViewManager.find(entityManager, EditorDto.class, id);`

The Spring Data integration allows you to use it almost like Spring Data Projections: https://persistence.blazebit.com/documentation/entity-view/manual/en_US/index.html#spring-data-features

```
Page<EditorDto> findAll(Pageable pageable);
```

The best part is, it will only fetch the state that is actually necessary!